# A term or phrase expressing the cheapening of a quality by measuring it in monetary terms

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I am looking for a term that expresses something along the lines of *to measure something of  value (especially an abstract, often positive quality such as bravery or effort) in monetary terms* in a derogative/pejorative fashion. Essentially as a result of such a measurement, the value of such a quality's perceived to be cheapened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In current usage you could call this

```
"a crass monetization of <bravery|effort|...>"
```

In recent colloquial usage "monetize" has moved from its technical meaning of "to convert to currency" to also mean "to make money from something" or an attempt to do so. The term itself, even without a pejorative adjective, has a slightly negative connotation as it often occurs in the context of "monetizing debt", a euphemism for a sovereign printing money to reduce national debt.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a single word, but *putting a price on something* is the behavior you describe.

Comment: I did consider this option before posting the question, but it doesn't really feel pejorative. Of course, it can be pejorative given a pejorative context, but it's pretty neutral on its own. However this is definitely a valid option, if the translation is done properly.

Comment: In reference to intangibles, I don't think I've ever heard it used unpejoratively.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use : "Commodification"?

It  is the transformation of goods, ideas, or other entities that may not normally be regarded as goods into a commodity.
Incidentally, as a commodity, they have a price.

In the Marxist theory, this is perceived as something quite negative.

Answer (score 1):

Google shows [eight entries](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&hl=en&q=mammonification+-ammonification&oq=mammonification+-ammonification&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=serp.12...508151.511363.0.518480.4.4.0.0.0.0.364.754.0j3j0j1.4.0.-rH_FHyhWEU) for the neologism *mammonification*, which occasionally is used to mean commercialization of things that ought not be commercialized.  The root of the word is of course *[Mammon](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mammon)*, referring to "The desire for wealth personified as an evil spirit" or to "Wealth, material avarice, profit".

The verb *[cheapen](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/cheapen)* has, among its several senses, one of bringing down the value of something by bargaining for it.  Aside from sexual senses, verb *[prostitute](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prostitute)* has senses "To use one's talents in return for money or fame" and "To make another person, or organisation, prostitute themselves"; a sense similar to those is used in wiktionary's example sentence, "Yet again a commercial firm had prostituted a traditional song by setting an advertizing jingle to its tune."  Verb *[whore](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whore)* has some similar senses.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use "mercantalization"? (I have not seen "mercantalisation").

The OED does not contain this word but gives one of the meanings of mercantile as "Having payment or gain as the motive; mercenary; (also) fond of bargaining."